# Using CountUp in Vue

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js

I'll start by saying I'm really new to Vue. I completed one project following a tutorial and this is the first one I've done on my own so far.

I am building a simple page to show the score between two teams. The score is being pulled from an API and I am polling this every 5 seconds and then setting the score variable for each team to the score retrieved each time from the API.

I'd like to animate this to count up to the new score, and am just a little lost as to how to do this.

I found [countUp.js](https://github.com/inorganik/countUp.js/) which looks really good, but the problem is I am updating a Vue variable and not an element and so I have no clue how to do this.

It looks like there is an [implementation for Vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-countup) but having never used npm I don't know what I am doing.

Here is my `app.js` file which contains my Vue code:

```
var vm = new Vue({

    el: '#liveCounter',
    data: {

        teamA: 0,
        teamB: 0
    },
    methods: {
        loadData: function() {
            this.$http.get('https://dummyapi.com/getScore)').then(function (response) {
                this.teamA = response.body.teama.summary.score;
                this.teamB = response.body.teamb.summary.score;
                console.log('polled');
            }, function(response) {
                //nothing
            });
        },
    },

    mounted: function () {
        this.loadData();

        setInterval(function () {
          this.loadData();
        }.bind(this), 5000);
    }
});
```

Can someone please help me implement a count up feature?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you need to do to use [vue-countup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-countup).

First install it using following command in your code directory:

```
npm install --save vue-countup
```

This will install this and create a dependency entry in package.json.

Now you have to tell Vue, that you are going to use an npm library which you can do using following(probably in app.js or where you have imported Vue):

```
Vue.use(window.VueCountUp);
```

After this two steps you can go ahead and use following in your template:

```
<vuecountup class="myCounter" :end="teamB" :duration="2.5" :options="{useEasing : true,
            useGrouping : true,
            separator : ',',
            decimal : '.',
            prefix : '',
            suffix : ''}"></vuecountup>
```

Comment: That hasn't worked for me at all. I followed your steps and added the `Vue.use(window.VueCountUp);` inside my template as that is where I import Vue yet it is just blank where the counter should be? There is no error in the console?

Comment: @James once try `<vuecountup class="myCounter" :end=2000 ....` instead of what I have given in answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share if anyone needs in the future

Template:

```
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 pr-0">
                <h4 class="display-4 text-right mb-0 count1">
                    <ICountUp
                        :delay="customer.delay"
                        :endVal="customer.endVal"
                        :options="customer.options"
                        @ready="onReadyCustomers"
                    />
                </h4>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <p class="text-uppercase font-weight-normal mb-1">Customers</p>
                <p class="mb-0"><i class="fas fa-user fa-2x mb-0"></i></p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
import ICountUp from 'vue-countup-v2';
export default {
    name: 'members',
    components: {
    ICountUp
    },
    data() {
        return {
            customer:{
                delay: 1000,
                endVal: 120500,
                options: {
                    useEasing: true,
                    useGrouping: true,
                    separator: ',',
                    decimal: '.',
                    prefix: '',
                    suffix: ''
                }
            },                
        };
    },
    methods: {
        onReadyCustomers: function(instance, CountUp) {
            const that = this.customer;
            instance.update(that.endVal + 100); //onReadyProjects
        }
    }
};
```